# How to delete this items in laravel5 (array)?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to delete the items I received correctly in foreach :

```
 public function prueba(){
        $detallcomanda = Comanda::where('idusuari','=',14)->where('estat','=',0)->get();
        if(count($detallcomanda)>0){
            foreach($detallcomanda as $detall){
                 echo $detall->id;
            }
        }
    }
```

I show the id correctly but when I try to delete with this form in foreach the laravel returns.

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

```
$detall->delete($detall->id)
```

**Update**

When I try this I recieve the content correctly , but when I use Comanda::destroy the laravel5 don't doing anything.

```
 public function prueba(){
        $comanda = Comanda::where('idusuari','=',1)->where('estat','=',0)->get();
        $toDelete = array();
        foreach($comanda as $detall){
            $toDelete[] = $detall->id;
        }
        var_dump($toDelete);

    }
```

This is the array

```
array(5) { [0]=> int(41) [1]=> int(42) [2]=> int(43) [3]=> int(44) [4]=> int(45) }
```

and when I use the following code , destroy doesn't work.

Comanda::destroy($toDelte)

**Update2**

I doing this

```
$prueba = json_encode($toDelete);
var_dump($prueba);
```

And I recieve the id correctly , but now I need to use explode to quit this items "[  ]"  , to get only the numbers i don't know how it works explode in laravel or is the same?

```
string(7) "[38,41]"
Comanda::destroy([10, 14]);
```

Comment: Don't remove them in a loop, it's a bad idea. Get all the id's in an array and do `Comanda::destory([$id1, $id2, etc]);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to delete them individually in a loop like that. It means you're running one query per item to be deleted. Instead gather all the IDs in an array and delete them all in one query:

```
public function prueba(){
    $detallcomanda = Comanda::where('idusuari','=',14)->where('estat','=',0)->get();
    $toDelete = array();
    if(count($detallcomanda)>0){
        foreach($detallcomanda as $detall){
             $toDelete[] = $detall->id;
        }
        Comanda::destroy($toDelete);
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your code and in the last  step I have an error with Comanda:destroy, i update the question

Comment: Check the documentation - http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete What I put should work fine.

Comment: I checked the documentation and I update the question (update2) , now my problem is how to use explode in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

`delete()` doesn't need any parameter. You're already calling the function on a model. Try this:

```
$detall->delete();
```

BUT as already pointed out, this is highly inefficient. You should only do that if you have model events that should be triggered by a delete. Otherwise the quickest way is this:

```
Comanda::where('idusuari','=',14)->where('estat','=',0)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you query a model, you get a collection. Collections have a method to retrieve model keys. You can use this method to get the keys of the returned models and pass that to Eloquent’s `destroy` method to delete them all in one go:

```
$comanda = Comanda::where('idusuari', '=', 1)->where('estat', '=', 0)->get();

Comanda::destroy($comanda->modelKeys());
```

It means you don’t have to do any horrible loops to build temporary arrays just to collect model keys—there’s a method that does that for you.

Comment: While this is certainly better, there's no reason to even run a select query. See my answer for the fastest solution.

Comment: @likasgeiter I didn't know if the OP was querying because he wanted to do something with the result set first or not.